# get select optgroup name as key in php

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

How to get the select optgroup name as post key and get the associative value with that optgroup.

```html
<select name="attr[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple="" data-style="btn-light" tabindex="-98">
    <optgroup name="attr[Size]" label="Size" data-max-options="1">
        <option value="One">One</option>
        <option value="Two">Two</option>
        <option value="Three">Three</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup name="attr[color]" label="inputTags" data-max-options="1">
        <option value="data,data2">data,data2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup name="attr[weight]" label="custom input" data-max-options="1">
        <option value="custom inpuot data">custom inpuot data</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

when i submit my form ***attr[]*** get the value as index like below.

```php
['attr'] = array(
    0 => 'Size Value',
    1 => 'Color Value',
    2 => 'Weight Value'
);
```

i want somthing like below

```php
['attr'] = array(
    'size'   => 'Size Value',
    'color'  => 'Color Value',
    'weight' => 'Weight Value'
);
```

Comment: try using `dd($request->all())` in your controller to see what are the things coming in your request

Comment: @Shobi after dumping i got the index array

Comment: The result you are seeing is from the name attribute on your select tag, not from your optgroup tags. What you are trying to do is basically making a single select into multiple select statements. The best and easiest option would be to split up each of your optgroup to a separate select statement. 
If that is not a option for you, then you need to write a some javascript to handle creating the form data in your desired format.

Comment: @OliverNybroe with javascript, that is pain in the ass